# Swift_Message not found error after swiftmailer installed in Yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2, swiftmailer

I'm setting up a mailer in a project using Yii2.  Swiftmailer seemed to be the best solution for this framework so I simply followed the docs.

In composer.json

```
 "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*"
```

Followed by:

```
 composer install
```

In my config I have:  (Yes, I just want it to save a file for now.)

```
'components' => [
    'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'useFileTransport' => true,
    ],
```

Then I placed this into a controller:

```
 \Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
   ->setFrom('from@domain.com')
   ->setTo('to@domain.com')
   ->setSubject('Message subject')
   ->setTextBody('Plain text content')
   ->setHtmlBody('<b>HTML content</b>')
   ->send();
```

My error is:

> PHP FATAL - Class 'Swift_Message' not found

I believe, after some research this has to do with the autoloader / lazy loading but the information I can find is spotty.  Most of it states that if using composer to install resolves the issue, and all of my troubleshooting has left me chasing my tail.

[Here's my stacktrace.](http://pastebin.com/MEX06qMz)  Thank you for your help.

Additional:

composer-asset-plugin - IS INSTALLED

vendor/composer/autoload_files.php DOES contain the line:

```
 $vendorDir . '/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/swift_required.php',
```

Comment: Sounds like composer didn't install Swift_Mailer for whatever reason. Have you tried running composer with the suggested arguments [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer#installation)?

Comment: Yes.  I have ran composer using both of those methods.

Comment: Folder `vendor/yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer` is not empty?

Comment: @vitalik_74 - No. vendor/yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer has what seems to be all of the proper content.

Answer (score 1):

I would love just close this embarrassment, but in case someone makes the same assumption as myself, i'd like to help.

> Does you entry script contains 'vendor/autoload.php' require? Does it
>   point to the correct file? Try to manually put die('swiftmailer') at
>   'vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/swift_required.php' - it should
>   appear at any application run.

via [(klimov-paul / yiisoft)](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/8021#issuecomment-91139742)

`die('swiftmailer');` had no effect.

`vendor/autoload.php` is not required.

I had assumed that the other extensions already installed in the vendor folder were in use.  I came to find that previous developers were not utilizing anything there and `require(__DIR__ . "/../vendor/autoload.php");` was not in the execution path.